# Trying to use form post without entity framework -- I Gave up, but will keep it open in case it helps someone...somewhere

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

While trying to get the basic CRUD to work in my Web application I have run into some problems. First, this is how I connect to my database:

```
public class DatabaseController : Controller
{
    protected MySqlConnection conn;

    public DatabaseController()
    {
        //Vul hier de juiste gegevens in!!
        conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=db;Uid=pw;Pwd=pw;");
    }
}
```

and this is how I load my rows initially:

```
 public Klant getAll(string naam)
    {
        MySqlTransaction trans = null;
        Klant klanten = new Klant();

        conn.Open();
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            string selectQuery = @"select * from klant;";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            //MySqlParameter naamParam = new MySqlParameter("@naam", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            //naamParam.Value = "%" + naam + "%";
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(naamParam);
            cmd.Prepare();


            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                int IdKlant = dataReader.GetInt32("idklant");
                String Naam = dataReader.GetString("naam");
                String Woonplaats = dataReader.GetString("woonplaats");
                DateTime Geboortedatum = dataReader.GetDateTime("geboortedatum");
                String Geslacht = dataReader.GetString("geslacht");
                String Beschrijving = dataReader.GetString("beschrijving");


                klanten.idklant = IdKlant;
                klanten.naam = Naam;
                klanten.woonplaats = Woonplaats;
                klanten.geboortedatum = Geboortedatum;
                klanten.geslacht = Geslacht;
                klanten.beschrijving = Beschrijving;



            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Product niet toegevoegd: " + e);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return klanten;
    }
```

and this is how I load them in the view:

```
@{ if (@Model == null)
 {
    <div>geen producten gevonden</div>
 }
 else
 {
    <div></div><br>
     foreach (Klant kl in Model)
     {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => kl.idklant)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => kl.naam)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "ShowKlant", new { id = kl.idklant }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ShowKlant", new { id = kl.idklant }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "ShowKlant", new { id = kl.idklant })<br /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>

     }
 }
}
```

Read operations work fine(to a certain degree).

I am capable of loading all the rows from my database, each with a Details/edit/delete/ option which uses the correct id from each respective row.

If I click on the customer with the id3, this link is loaded:

http://localhost:51596/Home/ShowKlant/3

Even when using the [HttpPost] overload above the actionResult like so:

```
        public ActionResult ShowKlant(int? idklant)
    {
        Klant k = new Klant();
        KlantDBController sc = new KlantDBController();
        k = sc.getById(idklant);
        return View(k);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowKlant(Klant klant)
    {
        return View(klant);
    }
```

The fields don't get filled.

[image: running out of ideas]

This is how the view looks in code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idklant)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idklant)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.naam)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.naam)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.naam)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.woonplaats)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.woonplaats)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.woonplaats)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.geboortedatum)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.geboortedatum)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.geboortedatum)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.geslacht)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.geslacht)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.geslacht)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.beschrijving)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.beschrijving)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.beschrijving)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I am probably missing something small...... but I think the problem might lie in how I load the data for the details page..... I just can't see it :/

My getById code is essentially the same as getAll.

The Get By ID Code is this

```
 string selectQuery = @"select * from klant where idklant = @idklant;";
```

This is what is different from my usual SQL.

If I do this:

```
 string selectQuery = @"select * from klant;";
```

it fills the data, but only with the last row in the the database, it doesnt matter wich of the customers I use, it returns/fills the last row.

everything:

[image]

unpleasant result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Your code calls `new KlantDBController()` and calls getById on that. My assumption is that the issue is happening there since that's what is apparently returning empty values

Comment: will do so immediately

Comment: And when you make this call: `string selectQuery = @"select * from klant where idklant = @idklant;";` can you show the line where you set the parameter for @idklant?

Comment: `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
                MySqlParameter idklantParam = new MySqlParameter("@idklant", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idklantParam);` here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that @idklant never has a value set.

You have a function called `getById(int idklant)`

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn); 
MySqlParameter idklantParam = new MySqlParameter("@idklant", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(idklantParam);
```

And you never set the value of the parameter, only the type. Before cmd.Parameters.Add you should have

```
idklantParam.value = idklant; // or whatever your parameter name is in your method
```

Comment: yo, thx for reminding me about the value. But sadly it hasnt solved the problem, when i use `string selectQuery = @"select * from klant where idklant = @idklant;";` it doesnt fill the form and `string selectQuery = @"select * from klant;";` fills it with the last row only again.  :/

Comment: Just fyi, my next answer will be extremely delayed due to time zones and the likes, have a nice day.